# iPad app can't display ⟨⟩ brackets

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

These brackets are ubiquitous in math, but I don't use latex because I get it in a wiki page of pronunciation. I ask it on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/227319/80007). The iPad app can't display them:

[image]

But when I am writing this question, I notice that it **can**, although those brackets are copied from one source:

[image]

Some tests: ⟨⟩ `⟨⟩`

> ⟨⟩

They can be displayed in the title though.

Comment: I can't see them in Google Chrome version 40.0.2214.111 either. I can see them in IE version 11.0.9600.17501 and Firefox version 35.0.1

Comment: Repo on iPhone running latest version of app. Displays in title, but not body.

Comment: Testing comments: ⟨⟩ `⟨⟩`

Comment: @BrianNickel works fine in comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**  While still completely out of our control, this appears to be fixed with the new system font in iOS9.

> [image: Screenshot of question with brackets]

---

This is an interesting case of character support and font substitution.  If you look at the question on desktop Safari, you will see the brackets correct everywhere.  If you look at the question in iPad Safari, you'll see boxes everywhere but in fixed-type code: `⟨⟩`.  If you look in the app, you'll see boxes in the post body and brackets in the title, editor, comments, etc.

Taking things one step further, if you copy the text "⟨⟩ `⟨⟩`" from desktop Safari into TextEdit, you'll see that the fixed sized text has the expected font "Menlo" but the normal text has the unexpected font "Apple Symbols".

So what's happening here? With the exception of the fixed-type font Menlo, none of the interface fonts we're using provide bracket symbols forcing the type system to engage in [font substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution), pulling glyphs from other fonts that support them.  It appears that desktop WebKit and the type system for iOS (CoreText) both support this kind of substitution but mobile WebKit does not.  Conversely, Matt's version of Chrome should support substitution but may not have a good font to pull the characters from.

Unfortunately, there's not much we can do here.  We don't know what glyphs will and will not be supported and I don't want to try packaging a new font to make this work as I can't predict the side-effects. It's little consolation but I will be switching the app to use Menlo as its fixed type font to at least address the problem there and make things consistent with Safari.